# Data From Database Not Loading into HTML table Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I would like to create a table that lists the rows from a small database (7 rows including header, 3 columns) to an HTML table.  I am working in Django and have checked "myapp"views.py, "myapp".urls, and the base.html.  I also checked myprojects url settings and did not see anything.

Any help would be great.

Windows 10
Django 2.2.7
Python 3.8

My code is below:

my\app view.py

```
def repList(request):
    all_objects_Rep=Rep.objects.all()
    context={'all_objects_Rep': all_objects}
    return render (request, 'base.html', context)

myproject\urls.py

urlpatterns = [

        path('', include('page.urls')),
        path('rep/', include('page.urls', namespace='reps')),
        path('home/', include('page.urls', namespace='home')),
        path('results/', include('page.urls', namespace='results')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

myapp\urls.py

```
app_name = 'page'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage_view, name='homepage_view'),
    path('Rep/', views.repList, name='repList'),
    path('userInput/', views.userInput, name ='User Input'),
    path('results/', views.results_view, name='results_view'),
```

````
myapp\base.html

    <div class ="RepList">
                {% block repList %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>District</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>

                {% for x in all_objects_Rep %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ x.District }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.f_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.l_name }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endblock %}
            </table>
                </div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You URL configuration is not quite right - you should only include `page.urls` once, not multiple times. Change your project URL configuration to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('page.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then if you visit `/Rep`, which is the URL you have defined for your `repList` view, you should see the correct contents being rendered.

Comment: When I changed the suggested change from myproject\urls.py I received the following error: ``Using the URLconf defined in kentucky.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='homepage_view']
Rep/ [name='repList']
userInput/ [name='User Input']
results/ [name='results_view']
admin/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, home/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: That'e because you're trying to visit `home/`. As I noted in my answer, the URL you have defined for this view is `/Rep` - so you need to visit that URL to see the view.